# Considerable difference between labels prediction accuracy in a multi-label classification problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am training an object detection algorithm with single shot multibox detector (SSD) for 8 classes. Seven classes are showing over 0.9 validation accuracy.  But only one class is not giving enough accuracy.

1. I have same number of training data in each classes
2. Some of training images are rotations and pixel differences of original images

Should I add more data to that class and retrain?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of bias and variance? These are very important topics used for "debugging" such problems.

Comment: Yeah . but it's one class giving bad results

Comment: How many instances of the bad class do you have compared to the good ones? Is the dataset balanced? Also, check the confusion matrix. Something that should not happen is one class being consistently misclassified with another one.

Comment: yeah data set is balanced 1000 per one class .  I think in might be the quality of that data class .

Comment: You'd need to follow the standard debugging approach. i.e. try training with smaller number of training samples for that class, what happens? etc.